# Sort a Primefaces Table that is filled with data from a collection

Tags: java, spring, primefaces

I'm having trouble getting the sorting to work in my PrimeFaces data table.

This is my .xhtml file:

```
<p:dataTable id="audiobooksTable" var="audiobook" value="#{audiobookListController.audiobooks}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        Audiobooks
    </f:facet>
    
    <p:column headerText="Audiobookname" sortBy="#{audiobook.title}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{audiobook.title}" />
    </p:column>
```

The arrows for sorting show up but clicking them has no effect.

`audiobook.title` has the datatype `String`. There are also other columns that I want to sort by (with data types `int` and `double`) but those also don't work.

The `AudiobookListController` returns `Collection<AudioBook>`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried the top answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051814/primefaces-datatable-sorting-not-working

But that results in a "no records found" message be displayed in the table.

Comment: Have you tried it with `List<AudioBook>` instead of generic `Collection`?  When in doubt follow the Showcase examples: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Primefaces 10**, try downgrading to **Primefaces 8**, there is an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6987) with sortBy.